# Правильно ли так говорить? (2)

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Правильно ли говорить: "Я проходила практику с китайцами.  Не все понимали русский язык, поэтому приходилось говорить по-английски"?

Answer (score 1):

Можно поправить **стилистику**: *Я проходила практику с китайскими студентами. Русский язык понимали не все, поэтому приходилось говорить по-английски.*

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что так можно говорить. Ошибок не вижу.